# How to change textview as per the timmings?

Tags: java

I have written some code. But it's not working as per my expectations. 
I want something like..

If time is between 12:00 Am to 11:59 Am ... It's shows Good Morning

If time is between 12:00 pm to 03:59 pm ... It's shows Good Afternoon

If time is between 4:00 pm to 11:59 pm ... It's shows Good Evening

My Code:

```
greetText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.greeting_text);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // Get current time
        int hr1 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if(hr1<12)
        {
            greetText.setText("Good Morning \uD83E\uDD17");
        }else if(hr1>12&& hr1<17)
        {
            greetText.setText("Good Afternoon \uD83E\uDD17");
        }else if(hr1>17&& hr1<20)
        {
            greetText.setText("Good Evening \uD83E\uDD17");
        }
```

Comment: And what does this code give you that you didn't like?

Comment: `TextView` is Android. So are you talking about Android code?

Comment: BTW, don't use `Calendar`. It's an obsolete, inefficient class. Use `LocalTime.now().getHour()` instead.

Comment: 4:00 is 16:00, and midnight is 0:00.  Your if statements are simply wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Its a simple logic bug (wrong values in if statements).